# Generate two object of the same mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, bdd

I'm using MoQ in C# to do some Unit tests/BDD tests, and I've often the need of generating the same object twice(because it will be potentially used in dictionary). Or something 99% the same but just with a different ID.

Is there a way to "clone" the Mock definition? Or to generate two objects with the same definition?

Comment: Write a method with arguments to build the mock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a helper method that constructs that takes in some parameters to construct the Mock object.

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    Mock<ITestObject> myMock = CreateObject(1);
    ITestObject obj = myMock.Object;
}

private Mock<ITestObject> CreateObject(int id)
{
    Mock<ITestObject> mock = new Mock<ITestObject>();
    mock.SetupGet(o => o.ID).Returns(id);
    return mock;
}

private interface ITestObject
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did tought of this, what about having exactly the same mock, is it mandatory to create two mock?

Comment: The Mock type doesn't have any copy/cloning abilities and it also isn't marked as `[Serializable]` so I'm afraid this is the best solution.

Comment: Okay, I was just wondering, the impact is not huge, but I would have found this nicer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a collection of data to unit test with, you may consider something like AutoFixture as well. It can work with Moq in the case of classes you want to mock. You teach AutoFixture how to create YourClass, and you can even set rules like "my IDs should be strings with capital letters and no more than X amount of them."

Then you'd just use autofixture.

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var tetsClasses = fixture.CreateMany<TestClass>();
```

This is really just to give you an idea. You can do quite a but more with it, and it plays really well with Moq.

An alternative is to use a data builder pattern to create your data. So you could start with something simple and just keep adding onto it as you find new edge cases on how you need to build the data. Just build a fluent API on it and build the data however you want.

```
internal class TestClassBuilder<T> : where T : TestClass
{
   int Id {get; set;}

   public T WithId(int id)
   {
     this.Id = id;
     return this;
   }

   public virtual T Build()
   {      
        return new T()
         {
           if(this.Id)
               Id = this.Id; // if you chose to set it, then assign it
           else
            Id = GetRandomId() // you can figure a solution here
         }
    }  
}
```

Then call it like:

```
var stubOne = TestClassBuilder.WithId(1).Build();
```

You can extend it to build a list if you want.

I like fluent APIs on data builders, because you can start to tell your story with the methods you create, and it keeps your Arrange section neat and tidy. 
Example:

```
var UnderAgeCustomer = new CustomerBuilder
                        .UnderAge
                        .WithFakeId
                        .InACrowd
                        .LooksYoung
                        .Build()
```

You could even add on

```
public static implicit operator T(TestClassBuilder<T> builder)
{
  return builder.Build();
}
```

And you wouldn't need to use the .Build() part all the time (I think build adds unnecessary noise). Just don't try assigning that to a var, it won't work.

```
TestClass MockTwo = TestClassBuilder.WithId(2);
```

I would say you could also use a fixture pattern to track of all this ... but between that and the databuilder, you may as well use AutoFixture and Moq as I suggested :)